# Custom Drawable added to Custom Listview is not Working

Tags: android, listview

drawable/magnitude.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/magnitude1" />
<corners
       android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
       android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
       android:topRightRadius="20dp"
    />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#444444"/>
</shape>
```

layout/singlerow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/magnitude"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And i set the Listview with CustomAdapter But the problem is that the drawable shape is not seen in the output.

Comment: Remove corners not working

Comment: Is there any problem to set custom background for custom listview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/magnitude"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="dummy"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

drawble

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#444444"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I need the textview in oval shape

Comment: same xml works for me put second xml in drawable folder.